# Angular-mocks error instantiating $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-mock

I have a very simple Mocha test (a copy of code that I have seen dozens of times)
[image]

When I run it, angular mocks appears to successfully load the injected resources and all their dependencies and successfully makes it to line 9.  When I step into the $rootScope.new() function it goes directly to the catch block.
[image]

with e as "undefined is not a function"

[image]

I am not understanding what is going on here.  The variable blockFns[i] is a function, or at least the Chrome debugger says it is.  So I don't understand why the call to injector.invoke fails.  Here is the stack trace.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `$rootScope` before you call `$rootScope.$new()` like so:

```
var $rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
  $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
}));
```

**Updated**

Actually the issue was that it should be `$rootScope.$new()` instead of `$rootScope.new()`.

Comment: Can you explain why your code (which I don't remember ever seeing) works and the code I was using (which I see everywhere!!!) doesn't work?

Comment: this is no different in functionality to `beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
}));`. You just get a subjectively cleaner looking beforeEach. The issue is that the method called should be `.$new()`, not `.new()`

Comment: I just figured that out.  Thank you.